# Z3 to show that if a^3=x*y*z then 3a <= x+y+z

Tags: z3, smt

I'm a total newbie with Z3 (started today). So far liking it a lot. Great tool. Unfortunately the syntax confuses me a bit.

**I want to prove that if:**

> **a^3 = x*y*z = m** *( with a, x, y, z, m (0..1) )*

**then:**

> **3a <= (x+y+z)**

I do so by trying to find a model satisfying that:

> **3a > (x+y+z)**

Here is the Z3 code:

```
(declare-const a Real)
(declare-const x Real)
(declare-const y Real)
(declare-const z Real)
(declare-const m Real)

(assert (> a 0))
(assert (< a 1))
(assert (> x 0))
(assert (< x 1))
(assert (> y 0))
(assert (< y 1))
(assert (> z 0))
(assert (< z 1))
(assert (> m 0))
(assert (< m 1))

(assert (= (* (* a a) a) m))
(assert (= (* (* x y) z) m))
(assert (> (* 3.0 a) (+ (+ z y) x) ))
(check-sat)
```

The model is unsatisfied.

Have I successfully proved what I wanted? As I said, the syntax confuses me since I'm a total newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

Explanation: What you wrote is equivalent to:

```
0 < x < 1
0 < y < 1
0 < z < 1
0 < m < 1
a * a * a = m
x * y * z = m
3 * a > x + y + z
```

Z3 says this is unsatisfiable.  Thus, if

> **a^3 = x*y*z = m** *( with a, x, y, z, m (0..1) )*

then it *cannot* be the case that:

> **3a > (x+y+z)**

because, if this did occur, then the SMT problem you posed would be satisfiable, which would be a contradiction with the claim by Z3 that the SMT problem is unsatisfiable.  If it cannot be the case that `3a > (x+y+z)`, then it must be the case that `3a <= (x+y+z)`, which is the statement you originally wanted to prove.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your solution is correct. Let me explain a bit about using Z3 to prove validity of a statement `A`. The key idea is that, in the classical logic, e.g., propositional logic and predicate logic:

- `A` is Valid iff `negation(A)` is Unsatisfiable.

This is a pretty well-known result. You can find it in many textbooks and materials, for example, in page 4 of [this slide](https://www.di.ubi.pt/~desousa/2012-2013/CF/ValidityChecking.pdf). So, validity of `P -> Q` can be proved via checking for unsatisfiability of its negation: `P /\ negation(Q)`.

In particular, for your example,

> `(a^3 = x*y*z = m) -> (3a <= x+y+z)` is Valid,

iff

> `(a^3 = m) /\ (x*y*z = m) /\ (3a > x+y+z)` is Unsatifiable.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer @Trung Ta,is well written and clear. I have upvoted it already :D . My question is however more in the line of the syntax and semantics of Z3 rather than the mathematical proof. Since I haven´t used Z3 more than a couple hours I want to know if the program I wrote is correct and actually represents the mathematical proof. Could you expand on this? A simple "your program seems correct" would be fine

Comment: @Trung I like this general explanation of the relationship between validity and satisfiability.  I posted another answer -- I suspect that people with a mathematical background are going to be more satisfied with what you wrote, while someone with a software engineering or programming background might be more likely to catch the idea from what I wrote.

Comment: @ElMarce Yes, your program is correct. You can refer to the detailed answer given by @ Douglas B. Staple. It explains more about your code.